# custom condition method attributes in C#

Tags: methods, c#-4.0, custom-attributes

I'm wondering if I can do something like this in c#:

```
    public CustomerManagerScreen() 
    {
        [TestAttirubute("CustomerManagerScreen_Load")]
            private void CustomerManagerScreen_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                CustomerLoad();
            }
    }
```

as you can see, method name is a parameter of TestAttribute, what I want to achieve is CustomerManagerScreen_Load will be discarded depending on the result of the TestAttirubute

this is the attribute class...

```
public class TestAttirubute: System.Attribute
    {
        private string _MethodName = string.Empty;

        public TestAttirubute(string MethodName)
        {
            this._MethodName = MethodName;
        }

        public bool hasPermission()
        {
            return (SessionManager.CurrentUser.UserRole.Role.Rights.Where(a => a.Resource.Code == this._MethodName).Count() != 0) ? true: false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Not sure what you're asking; seems asp.net authorization related but you ask in a general way.  also, `return true ? true : false`.

Answer (score 0):

Not like that, but with the `ConditionalAttribute` you can.

One restriction however is that your methods must return `void`.